# Java dependency injection

Tags: java

I develop Java programs in Emacs occasionally, and adding a dependency to a dependency-injected class is a common action.

For example, imagine adding the dependency `Qux` to the following class:

```java
// import statements here

public class Foo {

  private final Bar bar;
  private final Baz baz;

  public Foo(
      Bar bar,
      Baz baz) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = baz;
  }

  // methods here
}
```

The following need to happen in order to inject `Qux`.

1. `Qux` must be imported.
2. The field `private final Qux qux` must be added to the class.
3. The parameter `Qux qux` must be added to the constructor.
4. The assignment `this.qux = qux` must be added to the constructor.

After injecting `Qux`, the class should look like this:

```java
// import statements here

public class Foo {

  private final Bar bar;
  private final Baz baz;
  private final Qux qux;

  public Foo(
      Bar bar,
      Baz baz,
      Qux qux) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = baz;
    this.qux = qux;
  }

  // methods here
}
```

I use `emacs-eclim`, so the first step is already handled via automatic imports. The remainder, however, I have to do by hand, since I do not see any function in eclim that will automatically inject the dependency for me.

How can I use Emacs to quicken this task? The injection is fully defined by the type `Qux`; everything else is boilerplate, making it a juicy target for automation.